# PHP Message send with PHP Session

Tags: php, session-cookies, phpmailer

The aim of this script is to send an email, but instead of including your name and email, it would include it on the message because the website already has details of this from the PHP session. Currently the "2Email" works.. it can send a message to the recipient's mail box, and includes the user's input message. But it doesn't follow the template. I.E. It doesn't include the text "Sent via the dashbaord"

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["USER"])){
    header("Location: ../login.php?NotAuth");
}


 $to = $_POST['2Email'];
 $name = $_SESSION["USER"]["FullName"]; 
 $email = $_SESSION["USER"]["Email"];
 $subject = $_POST['regarding'];
 $message = $_POST['msg'];
 $Cc= $_SESSION["USER"]["Email"];
 $headers = "From: $email";
 $tracker = "This message was sent via the TrackerSystem dashboard";


$message = "Hi, "."\n".$message. "\n". "Regards, ".$name. "\n".$tracker. 
 $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 
 if($sent) {
     print "Sent successfully! XD "; 
    } else {
         print "The server made a booboo, the email didn't send :'( "; 
    } 


    ?>
```

Comment: Concatenate $tracker with $message.

Comment: `"\n".$tracker.` should be `"\n".$tracker;`

Comment: @madfriend that seemed to of done the trick.. when I tried using ";" I kept getting a Syntax error unless I forgot to remove the "." ..but anyway... it's working perfectly now :D

Comment: Be aware that your script mightbe easily injected with various badstuffs, like injection of things in the 'to' field. See e.g. http://phpsense.com/2006/php-email-injection-attacks/ (random google hit about php email injection). Don't just use $_POST, the user can have done anything with them. Sanitize your input!

Comment: I'm currently aware of that, but the most important parts of my web system are protected, and the only way to be able to send a message is to be logged in, the system is restricted to users I've added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a typo on line 19: `"\n".$tracker.` ? If so, that's what prevents your `tracker` being appended to the message.

What's actually happening: the whole expression on lines 19-20 (this one):

```
$message = "Hi, "."\n".$message. "\n". "Regards, ".$name. "\n".$tracker. 
   $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;
```

is being evaluated from right to left (if it even works, of which I doubt). So (first) mail is sent and result is assigned to `$sent` and (second) the whole concatenated string is assigned to `$message`.

To fix it, make `"\n".$tracker.` `"\n".$tracker;`.

Comment: that fixed it... tested it on my external website (so messages send) then after amending the script to create the session to include a user's email.. it worked. Cheers :)